# What does the word 'dicta' ('dita'?) mean in the song 'Who's That Chick?'?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, lyrics

The song ['Who's That Chick?'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_That_Chick%3F) by David Guetta featuring Rihanna features the following line in the chorus:

> She's been a crazy **dicta**, disco fever and you wonder...

Lyrics websites disagree on the word in bold: 'dita' seems to be a common alternative. To my ear it sounds more like /ˈdɪktə/ than /ˈdɪtə/ or /ˈdɪttə/. (You can listen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAc4zHEDd7o) - the chorus starts at about 1:10.)

I can't find any definitions of 'dita' (or 'ditta' or 'ditter' etc.) that make any sense in the context of this song.

As for 'dicta', there is a [sole entry on UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dicta):

> A woman that appears to be quiet when you first meet her, but once you begin unraveling her personality you realize that she scarily independent.

While this might fit the song, I can't find any evidence for it apart from [an anonymous answer on Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110215111018AAF26u4). The wording of the answer is very similar to that of the UrbanDictionary definition; both may well have been written by the same person. The definition happened to appear in December last year, not long after the song was released.

Perhaps the lyricist was out of ideas and decided to invent a new word.

Comment: In Albanian the word *dita* means "day".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for an interpretation of a lyric which affords no conclusive answer

Answer (score 4):

"Dita" is a name. Madonna takes it in the song Erotica and in her book "Sex". Dita was a  Polish actress. Dita Von Teese, also inspired by the actress, took her name.

Answer (score 3):

David Guetta's own youtube channel spells it DITA http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOdmf4N5aPE&t=1m42s

Dita von Teese comes to mind - she is a crazy diva :)

Comment: Nice find :) 
Referencing Dita Von Teese probably makes as much sense as anything else. 

(Incidentally, I think I agree with 'dannyyspencerr' in the comments - it sounds more like 'disco diva and you wonder...' rather than 'disco fever and you wonder' (as written in the video and in my question above). The amount of autotune/other effects might be throwing me...)

Comment: Until I saw the official lyrics, I thought it was "she's a mean and crazy diva...", but I'm notoriously, extremely, often hilariously good at mishearing song lyrics.

Comment: Then you need to go to http://www.kissthisguy.com/ or http://www.amiright.com/ however a LOT of the entries are VERY contrived

Comment: @JonPurdy cf [Mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to that question specifically, although I was looking for the answer which lead me here and I like what I found. Various websites have all the lyrics but in my opinion not one has them all correct. Between them I think you can find the correct lyrics. There's "she's a mean and crazy Dicta" "she's been a crazy dita"  "Disco Diva" "Disco Fever" (obviously diva is correct here). The one that seems to be the most wrongly heard though is when it goes "ultrasexual the night has got me love sprung" Loads of websites/YouTube clips have the words: "I will try to set/sex you up" instead. Listen to it, she clearly says "ultrasexual."

Answer (score 0):

We can't trust the video lyrics as it also says 'sexy' when the lyric is 'tipsy' (off the crazy juice) and 'hot' for bass so 'hard'.
I assume 'dicta' is short for 'dictator' - meaning she's telling guys what to do.
Someone from Barbados could confirm whether it's Bajan creole.
And it's 'disco diva' which is the same context.
But electronic music generally has an ambiguous drugs meaning - 'disco diva', addiction, adrenaline, baby, love, and so on. So the 'dicta' could also be a drug dictating how you behave. Lyrics always make sense when you think of the context. (It could be mean-eyed disco diva, hard to tell, the context is similar)

Full lyrics:

Feel the adrenaline moving under my skin
It's an addiction such an eruption
Sound is my remedy feeding me energy
Music is all I need

Baby, I just wanna dance
I don't really care
I just wanna dance
I don't really care, care, (I can feel it in the air, yeah)

She's a mean and crazy dicta disco diva and you wonder
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?
Too cold for you to keep her
Too hot for you to leave her
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?

Who's that chick? Who's that chick?
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?

Back on the dancefloor bad enough not to take me home
Bass kicking so hard blazing through my beating heart
French kissing on the floor, party's gettin' hardcore
E'rybody's getting little tipsy off the crazy juice
This will end up on the news

Baby, I just wanna dance
I don't really care
I just wanna dance
I don't really care, care, (I can feel it in the air, yeah)

She's a mean and crazy dicta, disco diva and you wonder
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?
Too cold for you to keep her
Too hot for you to leave her
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?

Ultrasexual, the night has got me love sprung
I won't stop until the sun is up, oh yeah
My heart is a dancer beating like a disco drum
Oh-oh, oh-oh, oooh oh-oh, oh-oh

Ultrasexual, the night has got me love sprung
I won't stop until the sun is up, oh yeah
My heart is a dancer beating like a disco drum
Beating like a disco drum
Beating like a disco drum
Beating like a disco drum

She's a mean and crazy dicta, disco diva and you wonder
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?
Too cold for you to keep her
Too hot for you to leave her
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?

Who's that chick? Who's that chick?
Who's that chick? Who's that chick?